# What template is used when using a string with has_archive?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

Can anyone tell me what template is used when using a string with has_archive?

I.e. `'has_archive' => 'catalogue'`

I thought it would be `archive-catalogue.php`.

---

Then I noticed via the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type), this line;

" Will use `$post_type` as archive slug by default. "

---

So I tried; `'has_archive' => 'catalogue'`

and amended the template to, `archive-products.php`.

Because `register_post_type( 'products', $args );`

---

But alas, no luck, I'm beyond confused, any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit: 12:02 21 Jun 2019**

Well, I feel like an idiot. catalogue-products.php, was working. I just wasn't calling `get_header();` in the template, so it appeared like it wasn't working.

Comment: This one http://wphierarchy.com/ doesn't answer your question? Normally in WordPress theming, if you desire to have a custom design for the archive page for a given post type, the file you should use is the name of the post type. Thus, for post type `catalogue` your template file name should be `archive-catalogue.php`.

Comment: did you try to set `has_archive` to `true`? `archive-products.php` should work if the post type is `products`

Comment: also, maybe regenerate you permalinks

Comment: I don't see your rewrite rules? In my memory, they should both be there, to change the slug. - and remember to flush again if you try to change the slugs

Comment: I got it working in the end, It was my error; A silly one at that. :) Thanks for the assist gents. +1.